# Zero in on: Have I used it correctly in this context?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, idioms, phrasal-verbs

> They are all of them competent architects. But I have ZEROED IN ON (= chosen) John to design my house.

Have I used “zero in on” correctly here?

Comment: I think it has more of a 'target acquired' feel to it. Not so far as 'seek and destroy', but possibly motivated by the [warplanes](https://www.britannica.com/technology/Zero-Japanese-aircraft) of the same name. I'm not sure that it has *quite* the right feel in the context of a simple *choice*. It might be ok if there was an element of pursuit to your selection process (i.e. along the lines of *we chose John and we're going to try to persuade him to do the design for us*). Otherwise, consider *settled on*. (Posted as a comment as I haven't researched the etymology of the term 'zeroed in on'.)

Comment: I think this is an edge case. Zeroed in on something + "to do something" isn't idiomatic and sounds a bit awkward to me. It doesn't really mean chosen. It means focusing on. To be zeroed in on is stative - you remain zeroed in - it isn't just an instance, so it doesn't really go with a *to do something* phrase. But you can rearrange the sentence so that it works - "but when choosing a designer for my house, I zeroed in on John."

Comment: I have voted to close this question as it comes under the category of ["proof-reading"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This includes questions of the sort "Is this right?" unless there is some principle clearly enunciated. Your title and descriptive sentence makes is clear this is not the case. I quote "Checking a text is proof-reading. This site does not offer a proof-reading service". This sort of question may or may not be appropriate to English Language Learners — you would have to check as I am not a member.

Comment: @David Please see "How can I ask about checking my text?" in the [help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We don't do simple proof-reading: but **we can help with specific points of difficulty.**

Comment: @NVZ — Thank you. So subtle that posters would never take any notice and reviewers would be unlikely to be aware of it. And unfortunate imo (not humble he) because it encourages proof-reading questions. But noted. Will try to prepare a more nuanced message another time. Perhaps there should be a set of prepared templates for reviewers.

Comment: @David I see. you could use this one I borrowed from a moderator and modified: `Please see "How can I ask about checking my text?" in the [help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We don't do simple proof-reading: we can help with specific points of difficulty. If you are learning English then [ell.se] may help, but they don't do proof-reading either.`

Answer (score 2):

"Zeroed in on" implies a thing that has been looked at for a while then considered the right thing to hit (as a target) use (plan).

I've never seen it used in the context of simply choosing someone, something.  It usually involves some sort of preliminary research before the "zeroing in" occurs.